# VirtualBox vshowvminfo error when using Vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have the following error when I try to halt, up package, or reload vagrant:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["showvminfo", "47b377d9-038f-42c6-a211-d6ca07e24751"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE (0x80080005) - Server execution failed (extended info not available
)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Most likely, the VirtualBox COM server is not running or failed to start.
```

This seems to possibly be an error with VirtualBox, but from the research I've done, no one has found a solution. Usually it is a complete reinstall, however I have a configured machine that I would like to package.

Comment: Please check if something looks strange in VBoxSVC file, you can find it in your user home's sub folder .VirtualBox. Other test could be done is manually start VBoxSVC in one terminal and do VBoxManage exercise in other.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error as well.

I guess this is a fairly vague error and can be caused by any number of things - in my case, my default VM location was mapped to a drive that no longer existed on my machine.